# How to open a window with dependency properties twice or more?

Tags: wpf, window, dependency-properties

It's a pretty straight forward question.

I have my main window in a WPF project, which I want it to open a specific window with dependency properties on it. Now the first time around it doesn't complain one bit about it. But subsequent attempts to open the window gives me an error about the dependency property already being registered, and that it can't register it again.

I tried keeping the window as a global variable, but then I get an obvious error about trying to re-open an already closed window.

So what would I need to do to be able to re-open the window, and not be stopped in my tracks because it tries to re-register the properties?

My main MO here is to recreate the window each time it needs to be opened (standard dialog/window procedure).

I register the properties like this:

```
public partial class MessageAndWaitingWindow : Window
{
        public DependencyProperty CustomMessageProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("CustomMessage", typeof(string), typeof(MessageAndWaitingWindow));
        public DependencyProperty WaitingProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Waiting", typeof(string), typeof(MessageAndWaitingWindow));
        public DependencyProperty WaitingPanelVisibilityProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("WaitingPanelVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(MessageAndWaitingWindow));

        // Rest of the class.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your either registering your `DependencyProperty` in the instance constructor or have the `DependencyProperty` declared non-static.
Make sure you define your `DependencyProperty` field as static and either register it in the static constructor or register it inline.

Comment: I should slap myself for not thinking about that... I've had a different window in which I have static dependency properties, and that doesn't cause any trouble... Thanks for the reminder though!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're registering your dependency properties in the wrong place. ie. not statically. Without code, one can only guess.

Comment: I'll attach a sample, forgot to do that.

Comment: @ThaMe90, Just add `static` to your field declarations

Comment: Yeah I figured as for your answer and Kent's.